# Minimum requirements for a function with non-zero Laplacian operator to be 1-1

Tags: functional-analysis, laplacian

Consider $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ two $C^2$ real functions such that their Laplacian operators are non-zero everywhere in their domaisn, that is

$\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}\neq0$

$\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y^2}\neq0$

What are the **minimum requirements** that $P, Q$ must have in order to a map $F=(P,Q)$ be injective?